how should I solve this FCM v1 403 problem...?
For the FCM V1 migration, I registered a new project and registered an existing Android package name there.
Project A: fcm project using the send method of traditional legacy method
Project B: A new project created to send push alarms in a new v1 method
If two projects exist as above and both have the same Android app package registered
I was wondering if I could get 403 when I call send of v1. I think this is the only reason.
I've also received the token properly through https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token , but if I just call send, 403 drops.
But the funny thing is...If I register another Android package, it will be successful.
403 is an error due to different sender and authenticator id... There's no reason to designate it so badly.
It's the same even if I create a new project several times.
If I specify one package in two projects, can 403 drop from send message?
So should I permanently delete the old legacy project?

For firebase http v1 migration you need to have authorize token, which you can get from firebase then 403 is not coming
